# Loading sass variables according to servername

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SASS to generate my css files and there are 2 versions. According to the url the user comes from, they should have a different colour scheme. I would like to add the colours to sass variables and then load the correct variables when loading the site. But i don't know how i can load the variables according to the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable.

Anyone who can help me?

SO in general i would need something like:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "foo.com")) {
@import("foo");
} else {
@import("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't put `@import` directives inside conditional directives.

But you can import from a dynamic path:

```
$path: server-name();
@import #{$path};
```

**UPD: this is false, you can't import using a variable.**

To have the `server-name()` function in SASS, you'll need Compass and some custom Ruby.

In your Compass' `config.rb` add:

```
# Assign a name to the project and pass it into SASS
$server_name = "monkey"
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def server_name
    Sass::Script::String.new($server_name)
  end
end
```

Adjust `$server_name` before compilation.

CSS is static, so you can't fully automate that. But if you're using some framework like Rails or Assetic, you can make it set `$server_name` automatically.

Comment: i Cant seem to do this, sass throws an error saying it expected a string or a url but got "#{$path}" instead.

Comment: Sorry vincent, i was wrong. It seems you only option is to wrap the contents of partials in mixins, import them unconditionally and then execute mixins conditionally.